# R program visualization + How to plot between categorical and numerical data

Tags: r, ggplot2, numerical

I want to develop a visualization graph with date in x axis and A,B,C values in Y axis. A value categorical data and B,c are numerical data. In the x axis, date should be represented in month and day like (01/07, 02/07). The problem here is A value is categorical data and B value is numerical data. The visualization charts should not be of bar type.It is like scatter plots.

I didn't know how to do this one. Your help would be highly appreciable. Thanks.

```
     dput(df)

     structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = 1:31, mon = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 
     6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
     6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), year = c(116L, 
     116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
     116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
     116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), wday = c(5L, 
     6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 
     1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L), yday =                         182:212, 
isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", 
"JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", 
"JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", 
"JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST", "JST"), 
gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
"mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Tokyo"), A =     
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,    
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N",    
"YES"), class = "factor"), B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 8L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")


        sample data:

        Date   A  B  C
        1  2016-07-01   N  0  0
        2  2016-07-02   N  0  0
        3  2016-07-03   N  0  0
        4  2016-07-04   N  0  0
        5  2016-07-05   N  1  1
        6  2016-07-06   N  3  3
        7  2016-07-07   N  5  5
        8  2016-07-08   N 10 10
        9  2016-07-09   N  9  9
        10 2016-07-10   N  8  8
        11 2016-07-11   N  7  7
        12 2016-07-12   N  6  6
        13 2016-07-13   N  5  5
        14 2016-07-14   N  4  4
        15 2016-07-15   N  3  3
        16 2016-07-16   N  2  2
        17 2016-07-17   N  1  1
        18 2016-07-18   N  0  5
        19 2016-07-19   N  0 10
        20 2016-07-20   N  0  9
        21 2016-07-21   N  0  8
        22 2016-07-22   N  0  7
        23 2016-07-23   N  0  6
        24 2016-07-24 YES  0  5
        25 2016-07-25   N  0  4
        26 2016-07-26   N  0  3
        27 2016-07-27   N  0  2
        28 2016-07-28   N  0  1
        29 2016-07-29   N  0 10
        30 2016-07-30   N  0  9
        31 2016-07-31   N  0  8
```

I tried this code. It works good for one value like B.. when I try to plot C value along with B, the graph seems different .

```
 library(scales)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = B)) +
 geom_line(aes(y=B,group=1),colour="#000099") +
 geom_point(size=2, colour="#CC0000") +   
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 1)) + 
 scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 day")
```

Comment: How can the A be put on the Y axis along with the B and C? Looks like the Y axis (for B and C) would run from 0 to 10; but where are 'N' and 'YES' on this graph? It doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: yeah. Thats what, my concern too. It's some important application. whenever there is yes in A, the other two columns B,C are varying.

Comment: What I meant was - I think you should consider some different way to visualise your data than overlaying a categorical and numerical variable onto the same axis, which really does not make any sense. The choice of visualisation probably depends on your application and what you wish to show. Perhaps you could do a separate plot of (B & C) vs (date) for each of 'Yes' and 'No', and line them up underneath each other for easy comparison. Or maybe you could use *colour* to indicate which B/C dots are 'Yes' and which are 'No'. Depends on what makes sense for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way to do it. I am not sure if this is ideal but hopefully helps in your case:

#### Using Markers

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github("ropensci/plotly")

library(plotly)
library(zoo)

df$Date <- as.yearmon(df$Date)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

plot_ly(df, x = ~Date) %>% 
    add_markers(y = ~B, marker = list(size = 15, symbol = "cross"), 
                name = "B") %>% 

    add_markers(y = ~C, marker = list(size = 10, symbol = "circle"),
                name = "C") %>% 

    add_markers(y = ~A, marker = list(size = 20, symbol = "diamond-open"),
                name = "A", yaxis = "y2") %>% 

    layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0, 0.9)),
           yaxis2 = list(side = "right", anchor = "xaxis", overlaying = "y", title = "A"),
           yaxis = list(title = "B/C"))
```

[image]

#### Using lines

```
#library(devtools)
#install.github("ropensci/plotly")

library(plotly)

df$x <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Date <- as.character(as.Date(df$Date))

plot_ly(df, x = ~x) %>% 

    add_lines(y = ~B, line = list(width = 5), opacity = "0.5",
              name = "B") %>% 

    add_lines(y = ~C, line = list(width = 5, dash = "5px"),
              name = "C") %>% 

    add_markers(y = ~A, marker = list(size = 15, symbol = "cross"),
                name = "A", yaxis = "y2") %>% 

    layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0, 0.9), title = "",
                        tickmode = "array",
                        tickvals = ~x,
                        ticktext = ~Date,
                        tickfont = list(size = 10)),
           yaxis2 = list(side = "right", anchor = "xaxis", overlaying = "y", title = "A"),
           yaxis = list(title = "B/C"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks royr2. Is it possible to make curves in the graph with B and C values to find the pattern. Also the dates with breaks of 1 day or 2 day.

Comment: Thanks Royr2.. This code helped me a lot and worked charm. Is there any ways, that I could only add month and day in X axis by excluding year.

Comment: Yeah - instead of doing `df$Date <- as.character(as.Date(df$Date))` just do `df$Date <- format(df$Date, "%b-%d")`